# How to send and receive SMS using Javafx or Java ME via USB dongle in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: java, java-me

I'm working on a project in which I have to send an SMS to a number and receive an SMS reply. I am using Java and Raspberry Pi. I have used J2me.

Here's my code:

```
public class SMS_Sender extends MIDlet {


@Override
public void startApp() {
    SmsSenderThread obj= new SmsSenderThread("123456789","helloworld");
Thread obj2=new Thread(obj);
 obj2.start();
 } 

   @Override
  public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
  }
 }
class SmsSenderThread extends Thread {
private final String thisPhnNo;
private final String thisMsg;

// Get the values from the Messaging midlet class
public SmsSenderThread(String passPhnNo, String passMsg) {
    this.thisPhnNo = passPhnNo;
    this.thisMsg = passMsg;
}

@Override
public void run() {


    // Creating the connection
    MessageConnection msgCon = null;

    try {
        // Open the connection with a port
        msgCon = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms"+thisPhnNo +":50000");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Create platform tp put a new text message
    TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage) msgCon.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);

    // Set the aircraft (here the SMS) for which payment is received
    txtMsg.setPayloadText(thisMsg);

    try {
        msgCon.send(txtMsg);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SmsSenderThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

> Starting emulator in execution mode
>      TRACE: , Could not open and read
>      file: C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame- 
>      sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000017.ii
>      java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit
>      Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000017.ii
>      - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
>      - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
>      - .unknown..(), bci=68
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30TRACE: 
>      java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit
>      Raturi\.\.javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000015.ii>, Could not
>      open and read file: C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame- 
>      sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000015.ii
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
>      - .unknown..run(), bci=5
>      - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5
>      java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit
>      Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000015.ii
>      - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
>      - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
>      - .unknown..(), bci=68
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
>      TRACE: 
>      C:\Users\Amit Raturi\.\.javame-
>      sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000011.ii>, Could not open and read
>      file: C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame- 
>      sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000011.ii
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
>      - .unknown..run(), bci=5
>      - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5
>     java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit
>     Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000011.ii
>      - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
>      - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
>      - .unknown..(), bci=68
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
>      TRACE: 
>      C:\Users\Amit Raturi\.\.javame-
>      sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\0000000f.ii>, Could not open and read
>      file: C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-
>      sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\0000000f.ii
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
>      - .unknown..run(), bci=5
>      - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5
>      java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit
>      Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\0000000f.ii
>      - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
>      - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
>      - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
>      - .unknown..(), bci=68
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
>      TRACE: 
>      C:\Users\Amit Raturi\.\.javame- 
>     sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\0000000d.ii>, Could not open and read file:
>     C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\0000000d.ii
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30
>      - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
>     - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
>    - .unknown..run(), bci=5
>    - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5
>   java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\0000000d.ii
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
>    - .unknown..(), bci=68
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
>    - .unknown..run(), bci=5
>    - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5
>   java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\0000000b.ii
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
>    - .unknown..(), bci=68
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
>    - .unknown..run(), bci=5
>    - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5
>   java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000009.ii
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
>    - .unknown..(), bci=68
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
>    - .unknown..run(), bci=5
>    - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5
>   TRACE: , Could not open and read file: C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\0000000b.ii
>   TRACE: , Could not open and read file: C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000009.ii
>   TRACE: , Could not open and read file: C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000007.ii
>   TRACE: , Could not open and read file: C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000005.ii
>   java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000007.ii
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
>    - .unknown..(), bci=68
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
>    - .unknown..run(), bci=5
>    - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5
>   java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000005.ii
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
>    - .unknown..(), bci=68
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
>    - .unknown..run(), bci=5
>    - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5
>   java.io.IOException: storage_open(): No such file or directory, C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000003.ii
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=0
>    - com/sun/midp/io/j2me/storage/RandomAccessStream..unknown.(), bci=21
>   TRACE: , Could not open and read file: C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\00000003.ii
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=26
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=8
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=7
>    - .unknown..(), bci=68
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=58
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=6
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=30
>    - com/sun/midp/midletsuite/MIDletSuiteStorage..unknown.(), bci=10
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=3
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=419
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=122
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=60
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=194
>    - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=2
>    - .unknown..run(), bci=5
>    - java/lang/Thread.run(), bci=5

Comment: Could you provide the work that you have done on solving this problem already? Currently, this question is very broad and likely to be closed without more contextual information/

Comment: @Evan Bechtol I have no idea to do so could you please send me a simple java code to send a sms and recieve a sms using usb dongle.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not going to send you code (and would be surprised if someone did), for a problem which you have not put any effort into solving! Not trying to be rude, but we need to see that you have put true effort into solving the problem on your own first!

Comment: sir will you help me Im providing the code on which Im working on but my netbeans not able to run it showing errors.

Comment: Please post your code and a detailed description of the error you are receiving

Comment: sir I have posted my code with error sir please help me out I really need it.

Comment: I think that your file paths are incorrect, you are getting a lot of "Directory not found ;/ doesn't exist" errors in your code.

Comment: sir I visited to C:\Users\Amit Raturi..javame-sdk\8.2\work\EmbeddedDevice1\appdb\ and there are all those files which are not accessed by the System and have no idea how to correct please guide me sir.